# Defining thresholds for cutting variable into the factors(qcut in pandas)

Tags: pandas

I want to cut the variable `x` on 3 groups:

```
new_var = pd.qcut(x,q = [0,.33,.66,1.],labels = ['low','medium','high'])
```

as `x.quantile(q = 0.33)` I received the value `0.6`.

My question is: Is there some function, that can cut x variables on n(in my case 3) groups, **but** instead of quantiles(like in qcut) we can define thresholds. In my case, instead of `0.6` I want to get `0.59999...`

Or alternatively: Is there possibility in `qcut` function, that the values(starting from 0.6) should be defined as 'medium'(not as 'low')? I mean, instead of using closed intervals to use open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) which allows to discretize data into defined bins using a half-open interval.

**Example:**

```
>>> pd.cut(range(1,10), [0,3,6,10], right=True)
[(0, 3], (0, 3], (0, 3], (3, 6], (3, 6], (3, 6], (6, 10], (6, 10], (6, 10]]
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [(0, 3] < (3, 6] < (6, 10]]
```